# How to approach for this webservice request?

Tags: integration, webservices, pdf, button, custom-link

Currently I'm displaying orders and related objects in a visualforce page. The new requirement is:

1. For every order a hyperlink/button will be added.
2. On clicking that button, a related document from SAP server will be downloaded using a unique number (order id).

> For example:
>   *(http: www.somelink.com/id=12345)*

How would I need to start this? I know how to expose a webservice from apex. I'm pretty excited because this is a great opportunity for me to learn webservices in salesforce.

Suggestions and references would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: document from SAP should be downloaded on local System or in Salesforce ?

Comment: It would be downloaded on local system of the user onclick of the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the object -"order" where you can see the record values for an order, create a formula(text) field

And try something like this::

```
HYPERLINK('https://somelink.com/'& File_Name__c , 
'https://somelink.com/'& File_Name__c )
```

where file_name__c is the file on that particular server/endpoint.

Note - file_name__c should be a value in records.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is good if you want an SObject field to be used as the hyperlink, otherwise you could just do the following in your VF page.

```
<apex:outputLink target="_blank" value="https://yourSAPServer/{!myRecordId}">Download File</apex:outputLink>
```

You could easily put this inside a repeat or a table too. As long as you just want to download the file, you shouldn't need to worry about webservices.